# SVG.js: Cannot animate rect width or height

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

Below is an example that attempts to animate width and height using SVG.js for a rect; width & height are both listed as valid methods that are animatable. The animation has no response.

It returns error: "myRect.animate(...).width is not a function"

Any ideas?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>SVG.js - Rect Animate Width/Height</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="//svgDiscovery.com/SVG.js/svg.js"></script>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body style='padding:10px;font-family:arial;'>
<center>
<h4>SVG.js - Rect Animate Width/Height</h4>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="svgDiv" style='background-color:lightgreen;width:400px;height:400px;'></div>
</td>
</tr></table>
<script>
    var mySVG = SVG('svgDiv').size(400, 400);
    var myRect = mySVG.rect(100,100).attr({x:150,y:150,id:'myRect',fill: '#f00','stroke-width':3,stroke:'black'});
    myRect.animate().width(300)
    myRect.animate().height(300)
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please report this issue to github. This is a bug. In the meanwhile use `size()`

Answer (score 1):

Your issue was fixed in version 2.6.2. width and height can now be used as intended